# Get info from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpquery

Hello i work on one project using JS, PHP & Mysql. I have 2 tables which are :

```
invoice (inv_id,date,total,paid,due)

invoice_infos (id, product_name,product_price,inv_id)
```

invoice_infos contains informations about all products of a invoice.

The column `date` of table `invoice` contains the date of the invoice, the column `product_name` of `invoice_details` contains name of product.

I want do a query which allow me view product selled in defined date.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample  and the expected  result

Comment: normally, the child table would be referred to as an invoice "line item", not "_infos"

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for a simple `JOIN` between both tables, using field `inv_id`. The `FROM` clause of your queries should look like :

```
FROM invoices iv
INNER JOIN invoice_infos if ON if.inv_id = id.inv_id
```

Starting from there, say you want to pull out all available information in `invoice_infos` and `invoices` for a specific date of sale :

```
SELECT iv.*, if.*
FROM invoices iv
INNER JOIN invoice_infos if ON if.inv_id = id.inv_id
WHERE iv.date = ?
```

Another typical use case is to *aggregate* date. For example let's compute the total price for each product sold on a given date :

```
SELECT if.product_name, SUM(if.product_price) sum_product_price
FROM invoices iv
INNER JOIN invoice_infos if ON if.inv_id = id.inv_id
WHERE iv.date = ?
GROUP BY if.product_name
```